# Forcing the removal of a ceph OSD

Tags: ceph

Our current situation is as follow: We do have a server that was used as a ceph OSD. The disks of this server crashed and were replace by brand new disks. Then the machine got reinstalled without the ceph components.

As a consequence, we do have a ceph cluster that 'believes' that the OSD should still be part of it and a machine that's being used for something else.

I'm following the official procedure on how to remove an OSD: https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/rados/operations/add-or-rm-osds/#removing-the-osd

Part of it is to issue a purge command:

```
ceph osd purge {id} --yes-i-really-mean-it
```

But the command fails with the following error message:

```
user@admmachine:~$ ceph osd purge 33 --yes-i-really-mean-it
Error EBUSY: osd.33 is not `down`.
```

I am surprised by the error message. More specifically, the id: `osd.33`

I am starting to wonder if I'm using the correct id. The tree looks like this:

```
user@admmachine:~$ ceph osd tree
ID    CLASS  WEIGHT     TYPE NAME              STATUS  REWEIGHT  PRI-AFF
  -1         339.99252  root default
 -17           5.82178      host srv1
   9    ssd    2.91089          osd.9              up   1.00000  1.00000
  27    ssd    2.91089          osd.27             up   1.00000  1.00000
...
 -33           5.82178      host srv2
  11    ssd    2.91089          osd.11           down         0  1.00000
  32    ssd    2.91089          osd.32           down         0  1.00000
...
```

My question is the following: what is the correct id I should use to purge?
Shall I use the id of the server (what I'm trying - here 33)?
Or should I use the ids of the disks (here osd.11 and osd.32)?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually using the wrong ids. I had to use the id of the osd and not the ids of the hosts. In this case I had to use the ids `osd.11`and `osd.32` instead of `33`.